# How to configure connmand to not to add the unnecessary route with IP 0.0.0.0 and GW 0.0.0.0

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, embedded, connman

The below route is sticky, even if manually deleted, it gets added by connmand (Connection Manager Daemon) with another interface name. If the specific interface is made down using ip link cmd, I see the same problem.

```
root@soc:~$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     0      0        0 eth0
```

Is there a way to configure `connmand` not do this?

Additional Information:
eth0 uses static IP address. On my system (SoC), I have 4 interfaces, out of which 3 use static IP addresses and the one uses DHCP. I have added the systemd/network file that defines the static IP for eth0 below.

```
root@soc:/etc/systemd/network$ cat 10-eth0-soc.network
[Match]
Name=eth0
[Network]
Address=10.10.11.2/24
root@soc:/etc/systemd/network$
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please add the interface configuration - ip address, netmask, etc., to your question.  This default route is likely coming from that config.

Comment: @roaima 
connmand is the service that runs in the background. Connection Manager Daemon. So when I manually put an interface down/up using "ip link set <iface> down/up", using the iface name on which the route is currently on, this connmand service deletes the existing route when the iface goes down, and adds the same route to the other iface that's up. Please let me know if I answered your question.

Comment: @SottoVoce I added the interface configuration to my question. Please see if this helps. This is my first time using this community, so bare with me. I will try to add more clarity to my question as I go.

Comment: Please add new information to your question rather than putting it in the comments. It's easy to miss here in the comments, and these are supposed to be only for seeking clarification. Make it easy for people to help you by building a complete question as best you can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`connmand`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/network/connman/connman.git/tree/) appears to be so minimalist and simple that it apparently cannot modify the route specified by DHCP at all.

After a quick browse through the source code, it looks like `connmand` will set a default gateway to 0.0.0.0 if the DHCP server has specified it that way. Apparently it used to include code to filter out such cases, but [it was removed because in certain IPv4LL situations such a route can be a valid configuration](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/network/connman/connman.git/commit/?id=74e97eda84c4c4fefbd00dceb767495dd062d290).

It seems to me that `connmand` might be too simple to handle your multi-homed host (= has multiple interfaces to different networks), and you may have to seek other solutions.

The fact that you can use `*.network` files with IP addresses suggests you have `systemd-networkd` available to you. You might try disabling `connmand` entirely, and using a `.network` file for the DHCP interface too, as it will allow more customization than `connmand`.

Specifically, you can set `UseRoutes=false` in the `[DHCPV4]` section of a `.network` file if the DHCP server provides a harmful route/gateway you need to ignore.

If you cannot abandon `connman`, then you might have to check the configuration of your DHCP server, and ensure that if it has no gateway address to give, it should not send the relevant DHCP option at all, instead of specifying it as `0.0.0.0`. But if some other hardware requires that a DHCP server always specifies some gateway, you may be in trouble unless your DHCP server is flexible enough to allow tailoring its offers for each client.

Comment: Yes you are correct, I have systemd-netword. And I figured out I do not need connmand at all. So removing connmand actually fixed the issue I have. Thanks for your help!
I will also check the dhcp configs, but the 0.0.0.0 entry in the routing table was getting added even when the interface that is dhcp enabled kept down. After removing connmand, I don't have this issue anymore.